# Detecting displacement of camera around something flat

Tags: android, image-processing, computer-vision

What approaches could be to the subj problem? I mean, there is a camera, looking to a plane (say, a picture, list of paper). Initially, it's assumed to be placed right normally to surface. Then, it starts to move, and i want to recognize:

1) small translations, shifting image on surface

2) scalings of image due to camera moves up/down

3) small transformations, due to camera small rotations

Specifically, it'll be run on Android, so, free Android libs are preffered

Upd.: image on surface is not going to be apriori known, but it can be assumed to be black curves on white, say a text.

Comment: You want to track a given object. If this given object is, let's say, rectangular, then detect its four corners and track them along the frames. This is harder than it sounds depending on what are your actual requirements (handling occlusions, high illuminations changes, etc).

Comment: mmgp: ok, i've updated post for details

Comment: The update just made it worse. Do you want to track a sheet of paper containing text or what ? It seems almost like you are trying to keep the description as a secret. As it stands, the question is meaningless and should be closed.

Comment: mmgp: really? meaningless? ok, i'll close if someone else vote for it

Comment: Really. Yes. You want to track something, but you can't describe what you want. That can't be answered.

Comment: mmgp: However, i'm trying nothing else then to automatically compose image of a large list with text or something else, captured by parts. So, there could be no additional details

Comment: I would be surprised if anyone can understand what you are describing. Can you show any kind of inputs/outputs you expect ?

Comment: mmgp: well, thanks, no, it makes no sence. i'll close topic in a few minutes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For sure [openCV](http://opencv.org/platforms/android.html) will help.. but there is gonna be quite a lot of work...